# Computing the inverse of a polynomial matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am working with a system of the following structure:

`L (k,m) = A2 k2 + A1 k + A0 - m B`

I have the matrices (`A2`, `A1`, `A0`, and `B`) numerically and would like to compute coefficient matrices for `L-1` such that I can evaluate `L-1` for a given combination (`k,m`) without computing a matrix inverse each time. Could someone point me on the right direction for this type of algorithm / manipulation? I'm not even sure I know the correct search terms to search the linear algebra literature on the subject. I'm using MATLAB.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)

Answer (score 3):

You can see from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Analytic_solution that the inverse of a matrix can be written as a matrix of sub-determinants divided by the determinant, so its entries are rational functions - one polynomial divided by another. Given that you know this, and that you can work out the order of the polynomials involved, it should in theory be possible to recover them, for example by fitting a rational function of the correct order to inverses computed at a finite number of points. You could then work out more inverses by evaluating the rational functions you found, instead of doing an explicit inverse.

However, note that the determinant for the three by three matrix example worked out below this is a sum of triples, so in your case it will be a polynomial of degree six in k, and with cross-product terms like k^4m. I suspect that this will save little or no time over computing the inverse as usual, and be numerically unstable to boot. However it does point out that any formula doing this will also be quite complex, as it amounts to working out a rational function of quite high degree.

There are some matrix identities used to avoid recalculation of matrix inverses, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_inverse_theorem. I don't think this is directly applicable to your case, but there might be something there, especially if your A and B matrices are not of full rank.

Comment: Exactly.  To analytically compute the inverse as a rational function in terms of `k` and `m` is exceedingly expensive for matrices of even moderate size.  It would be best to simply have `L` as an (inline) function and have MATLAB solve the linear systems as needed.